# PHP Marge Array in single array

Tags: php, arrays

all

I am using this foreach loop

```
foreach ($entries as $entry)
{
    global $wpdb;
    //$pname = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_frm_item_metas WHERE (field_id=228 && item_id=$entry->id) OR (field_id=301 && item_id=$entry->id) OR (field_id=120 && item_id=$entry->id)");
    $pname1 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id FROM wp_frm_item_metas WHERE (field_id=(SELECT id FROM wp_frm_fields WHERE field_key ='$field_key') && item_id=$entry->id)");

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($pname1);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

And its result is

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 984
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1047
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1077
        )

)
```

I Want to marge it in single array.
I tried this....

```
$genreArray=array();

foreach ($entries as $entry)
{
    global $wpdb;
    //$pname = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_frm_item_metas WHERE (field_id=228 && item_id=$entry->id) OR (field_id=301 && item_id=$entry->id) OR (field_id=120 && item_id=$entry->id)");
    $pname1 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id FROM wp_frm_item_metas WHERE (field_id=(SELECT id FROM wp_frm_fields WHERE field_key ='$field_key') && item_id=$entry->id)");

    $result = array_merge_recursive($genreArray, $pname1);         
}
```

But, its display me only last value of array.

Comment: What is `$result` and why do you merge into it instead of `$genreArray`?

Comment: Tell use more about what `$wpdb` is. Is it something from Wordpress? Is it a DB abstraction layer? Perhaps it has a method to return arrays instead of objects.

Comment: $wpdb is wordpress global variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$genreArray = array_merge_recursive($genreArray, $pname1);
```

Comment: Its work for me but, what i exact want is this loop function 5 times.now i am getting this Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 984
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1047
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1077
        )

)